# How to find files compared to the time of a specific file

Tags: linux, find

How can I search for files that were modified or changed 5 minutes before and 5 minutes after, a certain file. I have tried

```
mint@mint ~/Desktop $ touch -t 201210101315 /tmp/timestamp
mint@mint ~/Desktop $ sudo find . ~ -cmin -5 | xargs ls -l
```

to create a temp file with that time stamp and search for files changed within 5 minutes but I'm only getting files changed 5 minutes within current time.
What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-a` (and) condition, e.g

`find . -cmin -5 -cnewer /tmp/timestamp`

Will find all files changed in 5 minutes and newer than /tmp/timestamp

Comment: @jw013 You're right, thx

Comment: @warl0ck The -a (and) condition is not necessary. 
expr1 -a expr2 is same as expr1 expr2

Comment: @Jhonathan wait, why does it exists?

Comment: @warl0ck Manual for command "man" does not indicate it, only said to be equal. I think the option -a is to understand easily that the found files meet two conditions.